# Calling SQL Server Stored Procedure for Kotlin Exposed

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I am trying to access below mentioned Store Procedure from Kotlin Exposed ORM.

Store Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [HRMS].[ValidateCompOff] 
    @CompOffId INT,
    @IsStartFullLeave BIT
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Table Name] WHERE CompOffId = @CompOffId AND IsFullDayCompOff =0) AND @IsStartFullLeave = 1
        SELECT 0 as number
    ELSE
        SELECT 1  as number
END
```

But am getting the zero row in result set.

Code from the Kotlin:

```
val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val result = transaction {
                    exec(
                        "[Stored Procedure Name] @BranchId=$locationId",
                        explicitStatementType = StatementType.SELECT
                    ) {                       
                        val result = sequence {
                            while (it.next()) {

                                yield(NameValuePair(it.getString("Name"), it.getString("Value")))
                            }
                        }.map {
                            return@map it
                        }.toList()
                        return@exec result
                    }
                }
                return@withContext result
            }
```

When I try to access the above-mentioned store procedure which returns only a single value am getting the empty result.

However, the same approach works for the other store procedures which return the multiple rows in the result set.

Result in SQL server:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure but this looks wrong `explicitStatementType = StatementType.SELECT` . You aren't runnig a select you're running a stored proc. Please post one of the procs that work, I suspect your code is looking for the return value not the recordset

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the return value.
This " explicitStatementType = StatementType.SELECT" is for the selection of data that returns the result set and it is working fine. @Nick.McDermaid